# SQL code to capture contributions on two occasions

Tags: mysql

The following code gives users who contributed tags to an online community from March 1, 2016 to February 28, 2017.

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS tags 
FROM tag_events 
WHERE tstamp >= ‘2016-03-01’ AND tstamp <= ‘2017-03-01’ 
GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY tags DESC;
```

`tag_events` is the table, `tstamp` is the timestamp of the tag, `userid` is the user id, and each entry in the table contains information about one tag.

I'm interested in users whose first contribution within that period was at least two calendar days before their last contribution (so July 1 and 3 would count, July 1,2,3 would count, but July 1 and 2 would not count).

How can I modify the code?

Comment: Provide sample data and the desired output based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the result you want by calculating the difference in days between the first and last timestamp using the [datediff function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), like this:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS tags 
FROM tag_events 
WHERE tstamp >= '2016-03-01' AND tstamp <= '2017-03-01'
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING DATEDIFF(MAX(tstamp), MIN(tstamp)) > 1
ORDER BY tags DESC;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05037e/1)